Looking for a solution of $\sum_{i = 1}^{k} \sum_{{d}_{1}\, {d}_{2} = i (2k - i), {d}_{1} \le N, {d}_{2} \le N} [GCD(2 k, {d}_{1}, {d}_{2}) = 1]$
The double sum is
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{k} \sum_{\substack{{d}_{1}\, {d}_{2} = i \left({2k - i}\right), \\ {d}_{1} \le N, {d}_{2} \le N}} \left[{\left({2\, k, {d}_{1}, {d}_{2}}\right) = 1}\right]$$
where [...] are iverson brackets, (a,b,c) is the GCD, and ${d}_{1}$ and ${d}_{2}$ are divisor pairs of $i(2k - i)$, hence this is a restricted divisor sum problem.  The variable $i$ is also a summation index from $1$ to $x$ but I don't think that it is required for the answer.  I also suspect that just the inner sum can be answered.
So, I am looking for an expression of this sum and the best possible asymptotic expansion if achievable.
I suspect that the answer is closely related to the following argument:  For a fixed $r$ define
$$
{T}_{2} \left({r, N}\right) = \sum_{\substack{- N \le s, t \le N \\ \left({r, s, t}\right) = 1}} 1.
$$
From Randell Heyman and Igor E. Shparlinski, "On the Number of Eisenstein Polynomials of Bounded height", Applicable Algebra in Engineering Communication and Computing, 2013, defines a generalization of the Euler Totient function function
$$
\varphi \left({r, N}\right) = \sum_{\substack{- N \le s \le N \\ \left({r, s}\right) = 1}} 1.
$$
Now ${T}_{2} \left({r, N}\right)$ can be viewed as a generalization of $\varphi \left({r, N}\right)$ with two summation parameters.  In [Heyman, Lemma 4] the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion (PIE) is applied to $\varphi \left({r, N}\right)$ where in this case we can further write
$$
{T}_{2} \left({r, N}\right) = 
\sum_{d \mid r} \mu \left({d}\right)
\sum_{\substack{- N \le s \le N \\ d \mid s}} 1 
\sum_{\substack{- N \le t \le N \\ d \mid t}} 1 = 
\sum_{d \mid r} \mu \left({d}\right) \left({2\, \lfloor{\frac{N}{d}}\rfloor + 1}\right)^{2}
$$
where $\mu \left({n}\right)$ is the Mobius function and $\lfloor{\frac{N}{d}}\rfloor$ is the floor function.
If the argument of the main sum is $1$ we can write this restricted divisor sum as
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{k} {\tau}_{N}^{*} \left({i \left({2\, k - i}\right)}\right)$$
where ${\tau}_{N}^{*} \left({m}\right)$ is Truelsen function from  Conjecture 1.2 of Jim. L. Truelsen, "Divisor Problems and the Pair Correlation for the Fractional parts of ${n}^{2}\, \alpha$", International Mathematics Research Notices, 16:3144-3183, 2010, which is defined as
$$
{\tau}_{M, N} \left({m}\right) = \# (\left({a, b}\right) \in \mathbb{N}^{2} \mid a \le M, b \le N, a\, b = m),
$$
where $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $M, N \ge 1$.  Also define ${\tau}_{M}^{*} \left({m}\right) = {\tau}_{M, M} \left({m}\right)$.  There is to date that I can locate, no known details of Truelsen function of quadratic arguments.  So it sort of represents a notational place holder.
If this helps we can write the inner sums as
$$\sum_{\substack{{d}_{1}\, {d}_{2} = i \left({2k - i}\right), \\ {d}_{1} \le N, {d}_{2} \le N}} \left[{\left({2\, k, {d}_{1}, {d}_{2}}\right) = 1}\right] =
\sum_{{d}_{1}}^{N} \sum_{{d}_{2}}^{N} [{d}_{1}\, {d}_{2} = i(2k-i)] [(2k, {d}_{1}, {d}_{2}) = 1]$$
